# Generating select options using Json and Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html-select

This is an issue that has bothered me to no end. I need to somehow generate options for a select tag from a Json object using Angular. The code looks something like this:

```
<select id="cargo" ng-model="cargo.values.cargoList">
    <option ng-repeat="(class, name, weight) in cargo.values.cargolist
            ng-click="orderList()"> 
</select>
```

The class cargo.js looks a little like:

```
function setCargo(){
    this.cargo = {
        values: {
            forkliftNeeded: false,
            cargoList: {
                class: "class",
                name: "name",
                weight: "weight"
            }
    }
};

this.setData = function(input); {
    this.cargo.value.cargoList = input.cargo.cargoList;
    this.cargo.value.forkliftNeeded = input.cargo.forkliftNeeded;
}:
```

And the actual Json object:

```
[{"cargo":{"forkliftNeeded":true,"cargoList":[{"class":"A","name":"Book","weight":"1"}]}}]
```

The idea it to generate the appropriate number of option tags based on the number of items in the cargo list. Each option needs to display in order and also needs to display the class, name, and weight for each item (for the record, I'm delegating the forkliftNeeded item to a check box).

To make things even more complicated, I also want to make it so that clicking on a given option moves said option to the top of the list. Not just the options, either- it has to actually change the order of the Json object.

As you can imagine, I'm not nearly skilled enough in angular to make this work by myself. Any help you can give me will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I managed to make some headway. Turns out you can do just fine using:

```
<select id="cargo">
    <option ng-repeat="item in cargo.values.cargolist"
            ng-click="orderList()">
        {{ item.class + " " + item.name + " " + item.weight }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Now all I need to know is how to do the orderList() function. Is there a way I can get the index for the order tags on click?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Are those js functions wrapped in an angular controller or what? Also, you switch between `cargolist` and `cargoList`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `ngOptions`. Adding that parameter into your `<select>` tag will automatically fill out the `<options>` based on your array.

```
<select id="cargo" 
    ng-model="cargo.values.cargoList" 
    ng-options="option.class + ' ' + option.name + ' ' + option.weight as option.name for option in cargo.values.cargoList">
</select>
```

More on `ngOptions` here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: I looked into that. Unfortunately, it doesn't get me what I need (as far as I can tell, anyway). I would still need to modify those options such that clicking one of them would move them to the top of the list.